# set visibility of a gridview textbox inside during auto refreshment of the grid view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view,and include a textbox in the header of the grid view.
The textbox is using for search data in the grid view.
My grid view is also refresh with in an interval of time(6000 m.s)

In my current scenario the whole grid view is refreshing .
**My requirement  is -"During this auto refreshment of the grid view i don't want to refresh the textbox or set  visibility true always of the searching textbox."**

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

write this code in your Page_Load event or DataBinding event of the gridView

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)GridView.FindControl("yourTextBoxName");
txt.Visible = true;
```

Comment: The following error is occurring: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Specify the exact name of your textbox in the FindConrol() method as string